# Receiving "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" and "404" errors all over Chrome after attempting to change a port and flushing socket pools

Tags: http-status-code-404

Copied from my Chrome console on an Oracle page I am trying to access:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT visit-prod-us.occa.ocs.oraclecloud.com/Visit/js/oracleunifiedvisit.js?bust=20.2.2:1     
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT require.js?bust=20.2.2:8 Uncaught Error: Script error for: https://visit-prod-us.occa.ocs.oraclecloud.com/Visit/js/oracleunifiedvisit.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at C (require.js?bust=20.2.2:8:252)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js?bust=20.2.2:30:59)[enter image description here][1]
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404() /midtier/html/OUCollectionsProducts/:1 
maxymiser.js:1     
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT bk-coretag.js:1     
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT RCd05fed40167546e1a60f5530a8e102ac-source.min.js:1     
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT svrGP:1     
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT log:1     
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()svrGP:1  
Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received lPathCol_SJPF_col_4:1 Uncaught (in promise)
```

None of the content is loading. This is occurring on multiple websites and I am using this one as an example.

I cleared all my cached browsing history, cookies, cached images, and files. Re-flushed socket pools closed idle sockets, and cleared the host cache on that specific "Oracle.com" site. Nothing has changed and I am receiving the same 404 errors.

Also including a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyYlX.png